# mongoDB find from one collection and save in another collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to find a user from my user collection then inserting this exact user in another collection that have the same schema.

Here is my implementation:
(Controller)

```
const user = await User.findOne({ _id: id });
if (user) {
  const deletedUser = await DeletedUser({
    ...user,
  });
  deletedUser.save();
}
```

(Schema)

```
const User = tazweedDBConnection.model('users', userSchema, 'users');
const DeletedUser = tazweedDBConnection.model(
  'deleted-users',
  userSchema,
  'deleted-users'
);
module.exports = { User, DeletedUser };
```

It's working but the data in `deleted-users` is not like the one in `user`. I only get the default values in the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since mongoDB version 4.2, you can use [`$merge`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) to do it in one query (for older version use `$out`):

```
User.aggregate([
 {$match: {_id: id}},
 {$merge: {into: "newCollection"}}
])
```

Notice that the response is: `Fetched 0 record(s) in 0ms`, since no document is coming back. The document is instead inserted on the new collection.

Comment: it's not working for me. I tried

Comment: `await User.aggregate([
      { $match: { _id: id } },
      { $merge: { into: 'deleted-users' } },
    ]);`

Comment: I just tried in on my db and it works. Try directly on your db ui: studio3T, robo3T, compass...How do you know it is not working?

Comment: If it works for you please accept it, so it will be easier for others to find it.